# My .htaccess rules is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server, permalinks

So I'm lost in the .htaccess settings. So my I have my files in this path:

/var/www/html/my_site_name.com/public_html

and successfully setup my virtual host config and I created my .htacess as:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

So when i access my site at http://my_site_name.com, it's working fine but when I got http://my_site_name.com/other_place, it goes to:

IP_Address/my_site_name.com/public_html/other_place.

It goes back to the raw directory file of my site page.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These rewrites will redirect every request to a non-existent file or directory to  `index.php`, passing URL part after slash as a PHP argument. For example:

```
http://my_site_name.com/other_place
```

Is redirected to:

```
http://my_site_name.com/index.php/other_place
```

Opening, in fact, the `index.php` from the domain root directory.
It is up to `index.php` itself to process this request further.

Such rewrites are used by popular PHP-based CMSs, such as a WordPress.